# Default area height for Beamer overlayarea

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have recently been working with the `overlayarea` environment. In the example below, I like the transition from the first to the second slide: specifically that the `One` and the `Seven` appear at the same height. However, on transition to the final slide, I see that my estimate of `.2\textheight` for the *text height* parameter wasn't quite correct, and there is a jump as the text is positioned normally for the last slide. Regardless of this particular example, is there a way to calculate, or automatically choose, a default height for `overlayarea` to ensure such spacings are consistent throughout my slide decks?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Something here
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.2\textheight} 
\only<1>{
\begin{itemize}
\item One
\end{itemize}
}
\only<2>{
\begin{itemize}
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\end{itemize}
}
\end{overlayarea} 
Maybe also something here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Something here
\begin{itemize}
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\end{itemize}
Maybe also something here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with `overlayarea`s and such, you could ask beamer to replace the first item with the one from your second overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Something here
\begin{itemize}
\item<only@1> One
\item<only@2> Seven
\item<2> Eight
\item<2> Nine
\end{itemize}
Maybe also something here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Something here
\begin{itemize}
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\end{itemize}
Maybe also something here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]